# SQL WHERE + MAX query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get a row from SQL db, which meets 2 conditions :

1) Value 1 == 'A'

AND

2) date is MAX

```
----------------------------------------------
|                 Log                        |
----------------------------------------------
|  date   |     value 1     |     Value 2    |
----------------------------------------------
|  1000   |        A        |       C        |
|  1100   |        A        |       C        |
|  1200   |        B        |       C        |
----------------------------------------------
```

I can get the max value with following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM log
INNER JOIN(
   SELECT MAX(date) date 
   FROM log
)MaxDate
ON MaxDate.date = log.date
```

How can i add 1st condition to this query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The answer would be strongly specific to what DBMS are you using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and limit to one row:

```
select l.*
from logs l
where l.value = 'A'
order by l.date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support `fetch first`.  It might be `limit` or `top (1)`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the row where the date is max *among those rows with value1* = 'A', the following should work across all DBMSs and be easy to tweak:

```
SELECT *
FROM log
INNER JOIN(
   SELECT value1, MAX(date) date 
   FROM log
   GROUP BY value1
) MaxDate
ON MaxDate.date = log.date and MaxDate.value1 = log.value1
WHERE log.value1 = 'A'
```